# How to make a button go under a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button go underneath a div, however, the button float to the left instead of floating to the right. I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

So far this is what have:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sectiontitle">
      <h1 class="maintitle">Free Pick-Up<br>and Delivery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sectiondes">
      <p class="maintext"> We offer a free pick up and delivery service to your home or place of work.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionbutton">
      <button href="#!" class="button">learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}


.main{
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: url("../img/Home-img.jpg");
    height: 931.5px;
    width: 1920px;
    float: right;
}



.maintitle{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 641.6px;
    margin-top: 121px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;
    margin-left: 886px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.maintext{
    height: 68px;
    width: 489.6px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-top:0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.sectionbutton{
    float: right;
}

button{
    background-color: #1B325F; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    padding: 13px 28.5px 13px 29px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: -0.03px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;

}
```

I know for a fact the problem is my CSS but I don't know how to make the button go underneath the other div. The codepen is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/Yxpyop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}


.main{
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: url("../img/Home-img.jpg");
    height: 931.5px;
    width: 1920px;
    float: right;
}



.maintitle{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 641.6px;
    margin-top: 121px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;
    margin-left: 886px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.maintext{
    height: 68px;
    width: 489.6px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-top:0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
}

.sectionbutton{
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}

button{
    background-color: #1B325F; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    padding: 13px 28.5px 13px 29px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: -0.03px;
    margin-right: 392.4px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sectiontitle">
      <h1 class="maintitle">Free Pick-Up<br>and Delivery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sectiondes">
      <p class="maintext"> We offer a free pick up and delivery service to your home or place of work.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionbutton">
      <button href="#!" class="button">learn more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are my hero. Thanks.